# linear model for starting paramerters in nls fit

Tags: r, transform, linear-regression, nls

I read about using the log as an alternative for creating a linear equation so that I can extract starting values for an nls fit from the linear equation, in R;
Accordingly,

For equation:  Y=q/(1+bDX)^(1/b) where Y and X are my data; q,b,D are my parameters to be estimated. I created the linear model:

```
  X<-1:45
  Y <- c(35326L, 30339L, 23379L, 21877L, 18629L, 17627L, 15691L, 15435L, 
   14205L, 11732L, 10560L, 10592L, 9939L, 7491L, 4928L, 3427L, 8123L, 
   9027L, 8733L, 9599L, 8737L, 9135L, 8548L, 7279L, 8940L, 8459L, 
   8460L, 7700L, 6817L, 7167L, 7089L, 7091L, 7538L, 9206L, 9680L, 
   5876L, 7799L, 8384L, 10586L, 8623L, 7848L, 5534L, 6610L, 6539L, 
   6650L)
lmodel <- coef(lm(log(Y)~X+I(X^2)))   
q0 <- exp(lmodel[1])
D0 <- -lmodel[2]
b0 <- lmodel[3]*2/D0^2 
Start1=list(q=q0,b=b0,D=D0)
theta_hat2 <- nls(y~q*(1+b*D*x)^(-1/b),start=Start1)
```

This provides me the required results everytime. However, I want to fit nls to some other equations mentioned below which are rather difficult for me. If someone can help me make a linear model to fit these, I would greatly appreciate.

Equation 2:

```
Y=q*(-D+(b/n)*X^n here q,b,D,n are to be estimated.
```

Equation 3:

```
Y=q*exp⁡(-(X/D)^b here q,b,D are to be estimated.
```

Equation 4:

```
Y=q*X^((-b) )*exp⁡(D/((1-b) )*(X^(1-b)-1) here q,b,D are to be estimated.
```

I am attaching example dataset for this problem [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1ot1ymcghgoozm/Gong%20et%20al%20digitized2.csv?dl=0):

Comment: Hello, and welcome to _StackOverflow!_ I think you may benefit from a [really good tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions here. Consider editing your question after reading the tutorial, and I think you will have more success getting an answer. Your title should ask a clear question. _Good luck!_

Comment: Linearizing equations is one useful way to help find initial parameter estimates for non-linear solvers, yet as not all equations can be linearized easily it is worth investigating other methods for determining these estimates. I personally have had good success with the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm when used for this purpose.

Comment: @JamesPhillips can you share a link or suggest where can I try to use the  Differential Evolution genetic algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: For R, try the DEOptim package at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/index.html

Comment: @JamesPhillips still struggling to figure out how. Can you possibly show me an example for the eq: Y=q*exp(-(X/tau)^n). Trying to estimate q, tau, and n here. 
lower=c(100,0.01,5) and upper=c(100000,5,10)

Comment: I do not use R and so cannot provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that equations (2) and (4) are overparameterized so regardless of optimization algorithm used there will be problems.  In the case of (3) there is a syntax error and we need better starting values.  Test input should be contained within the question and we have provided it in the Note at the end.

### Equation (1)

`x` and `y` should be `X` and `Y`.  We can use the `plinear` algorithm to avoid having to specify starting values for the linear parameter `q` in which case starting values of 1 for the other parameters seems sufficient.

```
fo1 <- Y ~ (1+b*D*X)^(-1/b)
fm1 <- nls(fo1, start = list(D = 1, b = 1), alg = "plinear")
```

### Equation (2)

Equation (2) is overparameterized because if you multiply q by an arbitrary number a and at the same time divide D and b by a the right hand side is unchanged.  Removing q we note that D and b enter linearly and only n is actually nonlinear so we can use the plinear algorithm to avoid initial values for the linear parameters:

```
fo2 <- Y ~ cbind(-1,(1/n)*X^n)
fm2 <- nls(fo2, start = list(n = 1), alg = "plinear")
```

### Equation (3)

There is a missing right parenthesis in the formula given in the question.  If we fix that then the problme is that we need better starting valus. First try it with b fixed at 1 and then use the result as starting values for the full equation.  Again use `plinear` to avoid having to supply starting values for the linear parameter.

```
fo3 <- Y ~ exp(-(X/D)^b)
b <- 1
fm <- nls(fo3, start = list(D = 1), alg = "plinear")
fm3 <- nls(fo3, start = list(D = coef(fm)[["D"]], b = 1), alg = "plinear")
```

### Equation (4)

Equation (4) is also overparameterized so set D to 1-b in which case exp(D/(1-b)) is the constant exp(1) so:

```
fo4 <- Y ~ X^((-b))* exp(1) * (X^(1-b)-1)
fm4 <- nls(fo4, start = list(b = .5), alg = "plinear")
```

### Compare

We can plot the various solutions:

```
plot(Y ~ X, pch = 20)
lines(fitted(fm1) ~ X)
lines(fitted(fm2) ~ X, col = "red")
lines(fitted(fm3) ~ X, col = "blue")
lines(fitted(fm4) ~ X, col = "green")
legend("topright", legend = 1:4, lty = 1,  col = c("black", "red", "blue", "green"))
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

Test data should be self contained in the question and since it was not provided in that form we will provide it here this time:

```
X <- 1:45
Y <- c(35326L, 30339L, 23379L, 21877L, 18629L, 17627L, 15691L, 15435L, 
14205L, 11732L, 10560L, 10592L, 9939L, 7491L, 4928L, 3427L, 8123L, 
9027L, 8733L, 9599L, 8737L, 9135L, 8548L, 7279L, 8940L, 8459L, 
8460L, 7700L, 6817L, 7167L, 7089L, 7091L, 7538L, 9206L, 9680L, 
5876L, 7799L, 8384L, 10586L, 8623L, 7848L, 5534L, 6610L, 6539L, 
6650L)
```

Comment: Will it be possible to delete this question? I am new on stack overflow and need some assistance. 
I have included a wrong equation in the above question and don't want others to answer it. I have framed the question better and re posted it.